# Compiler injected code (e.g. for stack protection)

Tags: compiler-construction

Do any of you know a systematic overview of where the compiler can inject its own code into the binary? An example is the -fstack-protector option - here there is additional code in the binary at the beginning and end of a function that is not contained in the source code. Thanks!

Comment: Green Dragon book, surely?

Comment: I had already looked there, but found nothing (or, I was too stupid to look...) 
Do you have a concrete reference?

Comment: I don't know what this even means. The entire binary is generated by the compiler, and there isn't a one-to-one relationship between things in the source code and things in the generated code. (If there were, it wiuld be an assembler, not a compiler, but even assemblers do some code transforms.) The only plausible answer is "anywhere that suits its fancy".

Comment: We work in the area of safety-critical and high-reliability software and want to prove test completeness by means of code coverage. At this point, it is relevant if the compiler inserts code, because this should also be consequently tested. I know no one really does this, but with a certain demand for perfection, there is no getting around it. Compilers are not bug-free either - like all software.
I agree with you about the one-to-one correspondence, but in addition to that, the compiler really does add additional functionality like stack protection, which also wanted to be tested properly.

Comment: @Alex: But how do you define "additional functionality"? Additional to what, exactly? Bounds-checking code, for example, doesn't actually add any additional functionality to a semantically correct program, since the checks will always succeed. I just don't think there is a way to meaningfully define the concept of "injecting its own code". But maybe someone will come up with a definition which satisfies you.

Comment: @rici: For me, the -fstack-protector option is an example of additional functionality. Here the compiler generates code that has nothing to do with the source code. At the end of the function, we can see a decision in the object code for which there is no equivalent in the source code.

Comment: Ok. Here's the list of instrumentation options from the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html), which is where you'll find `-fstack-protector`. It's not a complete list of options which generate additional code, but it might give you some idea of the scope. There are also debugging and optimisation options which could introduce object cide "with no equivalent in the source", depending on how you interpret that phrase. (Register spills? Frame buffers? Compatibility with runtimes which use exceptions? ...)